# Sending data from parent to child thread

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

I'm writing some simulation software (railway) and am trying to add user control (via USB controller) instead of the automatic control.

The problem I am having is sending data from the USB controller to the solver.

I have my program running with several threads (GUI, solver, controller).
I am able to read the controller settings (via pywinusb) and send those as a signal to the parent GUI thread. How do I also send this data so it can be read in the solver without interrupting the integration loop?

The only option I can think of is writing to a file and checking it every integration step but I am hoping for something less crude.

Thanks

Comment: QThread has signal/slot support, you can safely send data from main thread to worker(child) thread using signals and slots.